# How to use Fields in Elm 0.13

Tags: user-interface, input, textbox, elm

I have been trying to get the fields to work, but keep failing. I have also been trying to look for examples, but the only examples I could find are using Elm 0.14, which use the new Channel API which isn't available in Elm 0.13.

So I started from the example offered in the [catalog](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.13/Graphics-Input-Field)

```
import Graphics.Input.Field (..)
import Graphics.Input (..)

name : Input Content
name = input noContent

nameField : Signal Element
nameField = field defaultStyle name.handle identity "Name" <~ name.signal
```

And in order to use the field I tried

```
main : Signal Element
main = Signal.lift2 display Window.dimensions gameState

display : (Int,Int) -> GameState -> Element
display (w,h) g =
    container w h middle <|
        collage gameWidth gameHeight
            (if  | g.state == Menu ->
                    [ rect gameWidth gameHeight
                        |> filled black
                    , toForm nameField
                    , plainText "*The name entered in the nameField*"
                    ]
                | otherwise -> []
            )
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
Expected Type: Signal.Signal Graphics.Element.Element
Actual Type: Graphics.Element.Element
```

Why isn't the element a signal anymore... The function definition clearly states it should output a signal, right? Now how would I be able to enter a name, that I would then be able to use inside a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elm 0.13 had some annoyingly confusing type error messages. Expected/Actual are usually swapped. In this case the problem comes from using `nameField : Signal Element` in `display : (Int,Int) -> GameState -> Element`. `display` is a pure (non-signal) function, but to be pure, you can't use a signal anywhere in there. To solve this, hoist the `nameField` signal up a level, to `main`. To use what is entered in the field, use the input signal:

```
main : Signal Element
main = Signal.lift4 display Window.dimensions gameState name.signal

nameField : Content -> Element
nameField = field defaultStyle name.handle identity "Name"

display : (Int,Int) -> GameState -> Content -> Element
display (w,h) g currentContent =
    container w h middle <|
        collage gameWidth gameHeight
            (if  | g.state == Menu ->
                    [ rect gameWidth gameHeight
                        |> filled black
                    , toForm (nameField currentContent) -- use something other than `currentContent` here to influence the field content. 
                    , plainText currentContent.string
                    ]
                | otherwise -> []
            )
```

Comment: So what if I want to extend this behavior to a menu for a game? What I understood from your reply is that I should send all signals, whether they are relevant at the time or not as an extra input to `display`. They will then be ignored when the menu is not visible and become relevant when the menu pops up. This makes a lot of sense. Now my only concern here is, how would I be able to send information back to the fields? How would I be able to send the current value back?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean.. Do you want to influence the information that's displayed in the fields? I'll edit the code to make more visible where you can influence the field.

Comment: For example. I have a player, who has a name. So `name` would be a field of the type `Player`. When the menu opens it would read out the name of the player out of the field and fill it in, in the field. Now the user could then change the name in the field if it would want to play under a different name and the field would become updated with the new name.

Comment: If a player has a hardcoded initial name you can set in the input: `name = input { noContent | string <- "InitialName"}`.  Otherwise it will need to be part of your `GameState` and you can use standard if or case constructs to separate the possible states in the `display` function and use something other than `currentContent`.

Comment: This seems to work! So what I learned is that name.signal can be used in the input part and name.handle can be used in the display part of the system to make both parts communicate with each other. Now to generalize this behavior to multiple fields and buttons, but that shouldn't be too hard (I hope ^^). Thanks again anyway!

Comment: After trying to get this to work in my code, I am still confused about what the handler is for. If I got it correct, then every changes that occur by typing something will come through the name.signal and I can update my GameState according. If I then want to show the menu again, I can update the field by using the last, `Content`, parameter. This all works, but it made me think about what in the world, that name.handle parameter is doing? I can change it with the handle's of other Input's and still works as before, nothing really changes. So what gives?

Comment: The handle tells the field where to send the user input. If you change the handle to one of a different `Input` during the run of the program, the changes from someone typing should get sent to that other `Input`. If you're seeing different behaviour that could be a bug.